# Voice input navigation

Tags: javascript, frontend, artificial-intelligence

I'm approached to make a voice input symbol to a site page that gets order through ones voice and execute the order, for example, envision somebody saying landing page and it consequently explore to the landing page.

I don't know how to go about it, please I need your help .

Comment: Here's a good resource that walks through the basics.. https://www.section.io/engineering-education/speech-recognition-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a voice input feature for a website that can execute commands based on spoken input, you will need to use a combination of web development technologies and speech recognition APIs. Here are the basic steps for creating such a feature:

1- Use HTML and CSS to create the user interface for your voice input feature. This will include elements such as a button to initiate voice input, a text field to display the recognized speech, and any other UI elements that you want to include.

2- Use JavaScript to handle the logic and functionality of your voice input feature. This will include code to initiate the voice input, handle the recognition of the spoken words, and execute the appropriate commands based on the recognized input.

3- Use a speech recognition API to handle the actual recognition of the spoken words. There are several APIs available that can provide this functionality, such as the Web Speech API provided by the browser, or third-party APIs such as Google Cloud Speech-to-Text. These APIs will provide the necessary functions and capabilities for recognizing the spoken words and returning the recognized text to your JavaScript code.

4- Test and debug your voice input feature to ensure that it works correctly and consistently. This will involve testing the recognition of different commands and words, as well as ensuring that the appropriate actions are taken based on the recognized input.

These are the basic steps for creating a voice input feature for a website, but there are many other details and considerations that you will need to take into account when building this feature. For more information and resources on creating voice input features for websites, I recommend checking out the official documentation and tutorials for the Web Speech API and other speech recognition APIs. These will provide more detailed information on the process of creating and

Comment: please mention that this is a openAi boot response